# Android The following classes could not be found - EditText (Change to android.widget.EditText, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Tags: android, class

When trying to view the Graphical Layout view I am getting the following error:

> The following classes could not be found - EditText (Change to
>   android.widget.EditText, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

The app works fine and I can edit the XML without any problems. I just can't load the graphical layout view anymore. In the Main.java file there are no problems or errors importing the EditText widget from the Android library.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2. Got all the recent updates.

I'm also using the latest Android SDK Tools 20.0.1

Here is the source. I've tried the option to Source > Cleanup Document and Format just to make sure the XML was correct.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
>         android:text="@string/button1" />
>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/editText1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
>         android:ems="10"
>         android:inputType="" >
>
>         <requestFocus />
>     </EditText>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

I managed to fix the problem.

I had to change

> android:inputType=""
>    **to** 
>   android:inputType="text"

The Graphical Layout view now works again.

Comment: Is it Eclipse? Check if the 1st Less Than character < is missing from the XML.

Comment: this worked
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501042/android-app-in-eclipse-edit-text-not-showing-on-graphical-layout

Answer (score 4):

this is because if you are using api  4.4W which is recently released for android wear

and Android wear doesnot support edittext

http://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html