# Android Only compiling with API 20: Android 4.4 (KitKat Wear)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, android-edittext

When I was building an app I attempted to place down an editText, but I got this error:

Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

After looking this up I came across someone else having this problem ([Android app in Eclipse: Edit text not showing on Graphical layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501042/android-app-in-eclipse-edit-text-not-showing-on-graphical-layout)). The problem was that the app was being compiled with KitKat Wear and KitKat wear doesn't support editText.

It should've been simple enough, all I needed to do was click on the 
green droid on top of the Graphical Layout XML and choose a different API. But for me it was only showing "Automatically Pick Best" and "API 20: Android 4.4W". And Automatically Pick Best just chose 4.4W. So I tried making the app again but when I went to the New Android Application, all that was opening up under Compile With was 4.4W. I tried choosing different Target SDKs and Minimum Required SDKs but nothing worked. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to download the API 19 or the one that you want. Go to Android SDK Manager and download the API, after that it'll be shown to you in the green droid of the Graphical Layout XML your new downloaded API, choose it and everything is gonna be fine.