# Android studio uses Android wear even if I haven't selected Android wear in project creation

Tags: android, android-studio

Playing with drag n drop Android studio 0.8.6 capabilities, I experienced

> Exception raised during rendering:
>   java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V

so, after reading [Android app in Eclipse: Edit text not showing on Graphical layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501042/android-app-in-eclipse-edit-text-not-showing-on-graphical-layout) I had to remove Android wear support.
I decided to try with a new project [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JBAZ.png), being careful to not click onto "wear"
Unluckly it seems to not be enough, since I still have Android wear in avaible API list [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOkzb.png).

WHat can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by removing 4.4.4W from installed SDKs in SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up "minSdk" and "targetSdk". You have selected 14 to be your minSdk and in the layout designer you can just select which API should be used to create your preview. Nothing more.

PS: AS is already on 0.8.9

Comment: 0.8.6 is the lastest version `https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download`

Comment: depends on your update channel. I can guarantee you that I have 0.8.9 running here from the `Canaray Channel`.