# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V error in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have developed android application on my PC using eclipse and everything is working great now I have copied that project into my laptop and imported it in eclipse work space.

My problem is when I am viewing xml files in res->layout folder eclipse showing `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V` error but if I run the project everything works great.

error is shown if I click on `GraphicalLayout` tab and there is no error if I am working on xml file.

Comment: My guess is there is a disconnect with the version of java Eclipse was built with and the version that you are running Eclipse in.

Comment: but project is running properly and there is no error while clean build so I don't think java is disconnected from eclipse

Comment: Which versions of JDK installed on your machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've encountered this problem before. Check to make sure that the android version you are using to render the GUI (in the GUI builder) isn't using API 20W or something else unexpected.  Look for the number next to the green android icon.

This link helped me out when I had the problem: [Android app in Eclipse: Edit text not showing on Graphical layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501042/android-app-in-eclipse-edit-text-not-showing-on-graphical-layout)