# Error in java.lang.System.array copy([CI[CII)V

Tags: android

I am getting a new problem  which may be due to version changes, but I don't know. The exception raised during rendering is as follows:

> java.lang.System.array copy([CI[CII)V

Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log .

> The following classes could not be found: - Edit Text (Change to
>   android.widget.Edit Text, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

its not getting the class of edit text. From where would I get/add it?

Comment: add some code snippets

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:hint="@string/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword">

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/24502370/826670. it looks like you are using android Wear to render it, change android version in rendered.

> Check the "Android version to use when rendering layouts" and make
>   sure you're not using a version that ends in "W" for Android Wear
>   (*e.g.* API 20: Android 4.4W). I don't believe Wear supports
>   `EditText`.
>
> In both Android Studio and Eclipse, it's the dropdown with the green
>   android in the layout preview's toolbar. You may want to set it
>   explicitly and not allow the IDE to choose the Android version
>   automatically.