# IndexNotReadyException - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

While changing the values of a `widget` in `properties` tab, `AndroidStudio` keeps on throwing `IndexNotReadyException`. But after few minutes while retrying, the error is not occurring.

**Here is the error log:**

```
com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.handleDumbMode(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:856)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.ensureUpToDate(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.processExceptions(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:930)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.collectFileIdsContainingAllKeys(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1190)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.processFilesContainingAllKeys(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1018)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.PsiSearchHelperImpl$26.compute(PsiSearchHelperImpl.java:1096)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.PsiSearchHelperImpl$26.compute(PsiSearchHelperImpl.java:1093)
```

I've updated the `AndroidStudio`, to latest one. But still the error occurs. Any fix or work around?

Comment: What did the documentation the error points to say about it?

Comment: I am using android studio 1.3 stable version and still getting same errors as you are. I only tried to import my android project eclipse based.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Happens because of the background `indexing` processes.

When the IDE is indexing, if we try to change the values in properties tab, then `IndexNotReadyException` is thrown.

Wait till indexing is complete.

Hope Google fixes this in `AndroidStudio`'s next release!

Comment: This also happens in IntelliJ IDEA IDE too, which is JetBrains' product, so, I suppose, it's on JetBrains duty to deal with the bug.

Comment: nope still error IndexNotReadyException find  in studio 1.5.1

Comment: 2.3.1  still there

Comment: 2.3.3 , still here

Comment: and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 29):

File-> Invalidate Cache and Restart

This will stop the old indexing process and start a new one.

After that wait for indexing, and let that project build.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error persisted even after restart.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem and found solution according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24606569/3965385), I have changed the API level 22 to 21, problem solved.

> API Level for XML layout was set **Automatically Pick Best ** which was API 22

[image]

And I change this API 22 to API 21:

[image]

and the exception removed.

Hope this help. Thanks

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?

Comment: Doing this is the same as clicking the visual editor's "refresh" button. So unfortunately this isn't doesn't remedy the issue at hand :(

Comment: Well this happens on debug deploys of the APK, not in XML preview pane.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried opening the project built in esclipse from default Open Project option from Android Studio, try Importing the project and open it.

Answer (score 0):

when that happend, run gradle method,
then incremental builds are rebuild and indexing is restarted:

```
task _deleteIncrementals << {
    def dirName = new File("${rootDir}/$project.name/build/intermediates/builds/debug/")
    dirName.deleteDir()
}
```