# Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation

Tags: android, android-studio

I have imported via GitHub a demoproject from Parse.com. The name of this project is MealSpotting. 
After the import, this error pop up: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation

```
Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.handleDumbMode(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:853)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.ensureUpToDate(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:802)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.ensureUpToDate(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:786)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.processElements(StubIndexImpl.java:250)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.processElements(StubIndexImpl.java:238)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.process(StubIndex.java:76)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.process(StubIndex.java:95)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.get(StubIndexImpl.java:227)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:144)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:134)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.java.stubs.index.JavaFullClassNameIndex.get(JavaFullClassNameIndex.java:48)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.JavaFileManagerImpl.findClassInIndex(JavaFileManagerImpl.java:145)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.JavaFileManagerImpl.findClass(JavaFileManagerImpl.java:138)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementFinderImpl.findClass(PsiElementFinderImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.findClass(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:102)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.converters.PackageClassConverter.fromString(PackageClassConverter.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.converters.PackageClassConverter.fromString(PackageClassConverter.java:47)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.getValueInner(GetInvocation.java:102)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.getOrCalcValue(GetInvocation.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.invoke(GetInvocation.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DomInvocationHandler.invoke(DomInvocationHandler.java:689)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidAttributeValue$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ce3af24b.getValue(<generated>)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.ActivityLocatorUtils.getQualifiedName(ActivityLocatorUtils.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.DefaultActivityLocator$RealActivityWrapper.getQualifiedName(DefaultActivityLocator.java:215)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.DefaultActivityLocator.computeDefaultActivity(DefaultActivityLocator.java:100)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.DefaultActivityLocator.access$000(DefaultActivityLocator.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.DefaultActivityLocator$2.compute(DefaultActivityLocator.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.DefaultActivityLocator$2.compute(DefaultActivityLocator.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:884)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.DefaultActivityLocator.getDefaultLauncherActivityName(DefaultActivityLocator.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFrameworkDetector.doImportSdkAndFacetConfiguration(AndroidFrameworkDetector.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFrameworkDetector$1.run(AndroidFrameworkDetector.java:93)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$7.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:369)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2350)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runWhenProjectIsInitialized(StartupManagerImpl.java:365)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFrameworkDetector.setupFacet(AndroidFrameworkDetector.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFrameworkDetector.setupFacet(AndroidFrameworkDetector.java:60)
    at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FacetBasedDetectedFrameworkDescription.doSetup(FacetBasedDetectedFrameworkDescription.java:119)
    at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FacetBasedDetectedFrameworkDescriptionImpl.setupFramework(FacetBasedDetectedFrameworkDescriptionImpl.java:53)
    at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionUtil.setupFrameworks(FrameworkDetectionUtil.java:104)
    at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionManager.showSetupFrameworksDialog(FrameworkDetectionManager.java:258)
    at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionManager.access$500(FrameworkDetectionManager.java:59)
    at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionManager$4.hyperlinkUpdate(FrameworkDetectionManager.java:200)
    at com.intellij.notification.impl.ui.NotificationsUtil$1.hyperlinkUpdate(NotificationsUtil.java:75)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.fireHyperlinkUpdate(JEditorPane.java:345)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit$LinkController.activateLink(HTMLEditorKit.java:877)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit$LinkController.mouseClicked(HTMLEditorKit.java:676)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6508)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

and I have no idea what I should do..
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192650/indexnotreadyexception-android-studio

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a possible solution: you can choose to invalidate and restart your android studio, then rebuild your project immediately. I have tried it and it basically worked.

Comment: Works in IntelliJ Idea too!

Comment: Super, worked for me (I had a problem with "jpa buddy" plugin with the same exception)! :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got the same error right after a rebuild.

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate and my issue was resolved by simply using the 'Clear Content' option for the Configuration in Services menu.
[image]

If this doesn't work for you, please try the 'Invalidate Caches..' in File menu for IntelliJ.

Comment: I immediately tried File/Invalidate Caches (without 1st clearing content). Selected "Clear file system cache and Local History" and "Clear VCS Log caches and indexes" (first 2 options) and pushed "Invalidate and Restart". After the restart everything was working fine again.