# IndexNotReadyException: when import a project in android studio

Tags: android

I am using Android studio 1.4 When I import any project  downloaded from  devoleper.android site then Android studio showing

```
`IndexNotReadyException: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192650/indexnotreadyexception-android-studio

Comment: no this is not answer of my question there is rending problem but here is when I import a project after importing direct showing this Excaption

Comment: Without more information everyone is left guessing.

Answer (score 1):

this project content a unusable folder I remove it and import successfulll