# Android Studio background error

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Everty time I try to change the values in properties tab i got this error:

> Please change caller according to
>   com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation

Is really annoying because I have to retype in the properties more times and this happen 1 time every 30 seconds....

I saw that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192650/indexnotreadyexception-android-studio) jet but couldn't find a solution.

I tried jet:

- Invalidate Chaches / Restart
- Change Api version in Editor
- Even complitely reinstall Android Studio, cleaning all cache,reinstalling sdk...

I have the last update.